# Bash Regex validation

Tags: regex, bash

Why is the below regex working on: https://regex101.com/r/nI8xB8/1
But does not work in a bash script

```
^(feature|bugfix|refactor|release|hotfix|other)\/[a-z0-9._-]+\/[a-z0-9._-]+$
```

With test string

```
feature/XXXX-23/xxxx-xxxx
```

But `feature/no-ref/xx-xxxx` works

Script

```
local_branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"

valid_branch_regex="^(feature|bugfix|refactor|release|hotfix|other)\/[a-z0-9._-]+\/[a-z0-9._-]+$"

message="\x1B[01;91m Some message. \x1B[0m"

if [[ ! $local_branch =~ $valid_branch_regex ]] 
then
    echo "$message"
    exit 1
 else 
    echo "\x1B[01;92m Your branch name is okay \x1B[0m"
fi
```

Comment: I think you need to show Bash code that demonstrates the problem. As given, I believe the code should work. Thus there may be something else in the way that the strings are built that causes the problem. Have you experimented with removing either the `^` or the `$` or both from the RegEx used in Bash?

Comment: In your test string, `XXXX` is uppercase and your regexp allows lowercase only. You can set the `nocasematch` Bash option or you can allow `A-Z` in the character specs. With `A-Z` added to one place, this evaluates to true (status `0`): `[[ 'feature/XXXX-23/xxxx-xxxx' =~ ^(feature|bugfix|refactor|release|hotfix|other)\/[A-Za-z0-9._-]+\/[a-z0-9._-]+$ ]]` (Side note: The backslashes before slashes are probably not needed; this looks like a `sed` expression escaping leftover (and even in `sed` one can just use e,g. `|` as delimiters to avoid escaping slashes).)

Comment: Alternately `shopt -s nocasematch` will do case-insensitive regex matching.

Comment: @Thabo, have to be careful with the online regex checkers: bash uses [POSIX extended regular expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/posix_002dextended-regular-expression-syntax.html), not PCRE

Comment: I always use a ' instead of " when defining REGEX so there is no interpretation.  `valid_branch_regex='^(feature|bugfix|refactor|release|hotfix|other)\/[a-z0-9._-]+\/[a-z0-9._-]+$'`

Comment: Thanks everyone I have found one that is working. See my answer below

Comment: Got a hint from the Character classes section from here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work with the below Regex

```
valid_branch_regex="^(feature|bugfix|refactor|release|hotfix|other)\/[[:alnum:]._+-]+\/[[:alnum:]._+-]+$"
```

Using the POSIX class: `:alnum:` and collation to also allow `_` and `-`

Refs:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions